# Error when running vagrant: "The host path of the shared folder is missing"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have downloaded a Vagrantfile, but when i run vagrant up in terminal the following message appears:

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider... There are
>   errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix the following
>   errors and try again:
>
> vm:
>   * The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Sync

OBS.: Using Ubuntu 14.10

---

I created a folder named Sync in my home.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this answer ?

Comment: Can you share your Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 10):

According to Vagrant docs host path must be either absolute (i.e. `/home/user/Sync`) or relative to project root (place where your Vagrantfile is).

Relative to project root means if your Vagrantfile resides in `/home/user/MyProject` then setting up path as `"Sync"` will create share from `/home/user/MyProject/Sync`.

Ref: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a space at the end of the path in config.yaml:

```
 source: '/Users/h/Packt/Code '
```

I've deleted this space and it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vagrant and Windows Subsystem for Linux then you can solve the issue creating a symlink

```
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/user/project ~/project
```

- `/mnt/c/Users/user/project` should match the Vagrant project in your Windows machine.
- `~/project` should match the path that is missing.

Note, that you may need to create any intermediary directories.

Comment: i had a space in the folder name in windows (no WSL) - symlinking solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you are in linux or mac. Type in "pwd" and enter in the terminal where Homestead.yml is.

Mine is "/home/idhamhafidz/Code/opp190-ama"

Then go to your Homestead.yml and edit the folders section like in the image below:
[image]

Then quit edit Homesteady.yml and re-run vagrant up again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone just encountering this issue and having a hard time finding a conclusion the answer by @megawebmaster would be the correct approach in giving the relative path to the folder: `"/home/(your-pc-username)/Sync/"`.

Also with a Vagrantfile being ruby-based I personally use ruby's `ENV` object:
`#{ENV["HOME"]}/Sync` should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and
`mkdir ~/Sync` help me solve it.